# Upload a image url to s3 directly using ng-file-upload or any other method

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

there is scenario in my project where I need to upload an image url to s3. (like "https://.net/23123123/picture" to s3). What is the correct way to do it? Do I need to convert the url to blob and then convert this blob to file? and then use ng-file-upload (using this plugin I am already uploading images to s3.) to upload this to s3 or is there any other way to handle this uploading process?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```
Upload.upload({..., file: Upload.urlToBlob(url), ...})
```

which will try to download the file from the url first then convert it to blob to upload.
Note that depending on the url the server may not allow CORS access so you may not be able to download the image if the cross origin access is not allowed.